# Refresh webpart when New item is added

Tags: web-part, item, refresh

I would like a script for Refreshing a webpart when a new item is added to te list.
Can anyone help me with this?

Kind regards,
Vincent van den Eijnde
SharepointServices.nl

Answer (score 3):

The XsltListViewWebPart, which is one of the default web parts you can drag onto a form in SharePoint Designer, has an "Auto Refresh" and a "ManualRefresh" property which may get you what you want. Read further below for a script that addresses your question specifically.

FWIW, if you create it programatically, I just happen to have a handy snippet:

```
        Dim wp3 As New XsltListViewWebPart()
        wp3.Description = "Links related to specific log items in blah blah"
        wp3.AllowClose = False
        wp3.ViewFlag = "8388621"
        wp3.AllowConnect = True
        wp3.ChromeState = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeState.Normal
        wp3.TitleUrl = String.Format("/Lists/{0}", m_linksListName)
        wp3.AutoRefresh = False
        wp3.ManualRefresh = True 'causes refresh button to show
        wp3.AutoRefreshInterval = 15
        wp3.ExportMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartExportMode.All
        wp3.CatalogIconImageUrl = "/_layouts/images/itgen.png"
        wp3.ViewGuid = view2.ID.ToString()
        wp3.XmlDefinition = view2.GetViewXml()
        wp3.ParameterBindings = "<ParameterBinding Name=""Param1"" & _
                                 " Location=""QueryString(ID)"" DefaultValue=""""/> "
        wp3.ListId = m_linksList.ID
        wp3.ListName = m_linksList.ID.ToString
```

You'll notice it can set to AutoRefresh, or you can cause a little recycle icon to render if you set ManualRefresh to true.

---

Now, what I did in one of my solutions, was set ManualRefresh=true so that the little recycle icon would be rendered by SharePoint. Then, in my custom script that responded to the item being added (which happened in a modal dialog) I used a bit of jQuery to 'click' the icon on behalf of the user who just added the item.

```
// ribbon button called this to pop open dialog for adding a 'link' item:
function addlinks_display(listid, itemid) {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 650;
    options.height = 450;
    options.url = "/_layouts/AddLink.aspx?DispForm=1&ListID=" + listid + "&ItemID=" + itemid;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, addlink_modalDialogClosedCallback);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

// dialog closed callback
function addlink_modalDialogClosedCallback(result, value) {
    if (value == 1) {
        currentStatusId[currentStatusId.length] = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Link Added",
                    "Your link was successfully added.",
                    true);
        SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(currentStatusId[currentStatusId.length - 1], "Green");
        successfullyClosedMessage = value;
        refreshWebpartDetails();
    }

    if (value == '0') {
        //error logic here
    }
    setTimeout(RemoveStatus, 8000);
}

// refresh
function refreshWebpartDetails() {
    $('#WebPartWPQ1').find('#ManualRefresh').click(); //refresh webpart using SP ajax
}
```