# Refresh the data on the webpart without entire Page refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

The data from the list is displayed on the page using content editor webpart as a scrolling text. The requirement is whenever the list is updated with new items, the data displayed on the page using CEWP should be updated automatically without a entire page refresh.
The script to display the scrolling text is in a text file uploaded into the library and linked to the webpart.
I tried using SetTimeout and SetInterval, but nothing is working.
Please suggest with available options

Thank You

Comment: Please post relevant code from that text file.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint 2010 introduces a new Ajax option has been added to  many webparts to enable auto refresh of webpart without refreshing the entire web page. This feature is available out of the box in SharePoint 2010 and no additional development is required.

How to use Auto Refresh Web parts in SharePoint 2010:

In SharePoint 2010, web parts have a new section in their tool panes - Ajax Options:

[image]

The key option is the Enable Asynchronous Automatic Refresh. Checking this will enable the Auto Refresh feature on the webpart. The Auto Refreshing Interval is the time interval in which webpart will get refreshed automatically.

Thanks,

Comment: Do we have this option available in SharePoint 2013?(SharePoint online)

Comment: yes you have this option in sharepoint 2013 also

Comment: This option is enabled only in data view webpart.

Answer (score 3):

Set "Show Manual Refresh Button" setting from previous post and call from Your js script:

```
jQuery('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').find('#ManualRefresh').click();
```

Took this solution from another [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53711/refresh-webpart-when-new-item-is-added).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
function RefreshWebpart(webpartId)
{
    var webpart = document.querySelector("div[webpartid='" + webpartId + "']");
    var listviewtable = webpart.querySelector("table.ms-listviewtable");
    __doPostBack(listviewtable.id, "cancel");
}
```