# SharePoint 2013 Document Library Web Part

Tags: web-part, document-library, page-layout, folder, boot-strap

I am wondering if anyone can possibly answer by question, I have created a new page layout using the Bootstrap framework and then added approximately 5 web part zones, in each web part zone I have a document library or a content editor etc...

At the bottom of the page layout I have a document library with multiple folders, users are currently complaining that when they click in to a folder the page refreshes and takes them back up to the top of the page leaving the frustrated at the fact they have to scroll all the way back down to the bottom of the page again.

I would appreciate any help or advice anyone might have with this.

Answer (score 0):

The URL changes when user clicks on the folder. It means the page always refresh after clicking on the folder in Document Library.

It is the default behavior of SharePoint.

Comment: Is there no way of changing this default behavior? Or is there a way of maybe adding an anchor to the page when the folder is clicked so it will reload in the same place?

Comment: There is no workaround for default SharePoint behavior. You need to put your webpart zone inside AJAX updatepanel. but i haven't really tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Some Jquery might help you out here...Try this link...let us know if it works

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092735/refresh-scroll-to-bottom

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work, I dont want the page to always scroll down either, I only want it to happen when a user clicks in to a folder. I want it to scroll to a specific element also not just to the bottom of the page, I need it to scroll for instance to web part zone 5.

Comment: How About this..Did you try it :http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138668/refresh-the-data-on-the-webpart-without-entire-page-refresh